# How to conver this list/tuple in the following list in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this:

```
x = [[(u'reads_2.fq',), (u'reads_2.fq',), (u'reads_2.fq',), (u'reads_2.fq',), (u'reads_2.fq',)]]
```

I want to convert this list into like this:

```
x = ['reads_2.fq', 'reads_2.fq', 'reads_2.fq', 'reads_2.fq', 'reads_2.fq']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
>>> x = [[(u'reads_2.fq',), (u'reads_2.fq',), (u'reads_2.fq',), (u'reads_2.fq',), (u'reads_2.fq',)]]
>>> [y[0] for y in x[0]]
[u'reads_2.fq', u'reads_2.fq', u'reads_2.fq', u'reads_2.fq', u'reads_2.fq']
```

If the inner tuples contain more than one item then use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(x[0]))
[u'reads_2.fq', u'reads_2.fq', u'reads_2.fq', u'reads_2.fq', u'reads_2.fq']
```